# Call method on subclass from the parent class when a file is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a number of cleanup scripts in my Rails application which are all classes that inherit from a common `CleanupScript` class. In order to run a cleanup script, I usually write `Script.run unless Rails.env.test?` at the bottom of each file (so that it can be run through `rails runner`).

Obviously, this is not particularly DRY, and I'm thinking that there must be a way within the superclass to set this up automatically. I'm aware of `Kernel#at_exit`, but I'm not sure if I can somehow use this within `CleanupScript` to know which script class to use, or if this is even the correct process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at_exit` does seem to be an appropriate way to solve this problem, this is what I ended up doing:

```
class CleanupScript
  cattr_accessor :autorun
  self.autorun = !Rails.env.test?

  def self.inherited(klass)
    at_exit do
      klass.run if klass.autorun
    end
  end
end
```

This allows subclasses to specify `SubclassedCleanupScript.autorun = false` if I want to disable autorun for some reason (and also automatically disables autorunning for the test env), but in general will automatically run the class when its script is loaded by `rails runner`.